# How to resolve the problem with the SQL LIKE operator

Tags: sql-like

There is a table '**Phones**', which includes a column '**phone_no**', declared as **varchar(20)**. It can be **NULL**, too.
Some of the values stored in this column are:
'(310) 369-1000', '(415) 623-1000', '(310) 449-3000', '(323) 956-8398', and '(800) 864-8377'.
I would like to filter out all the records where the phone number ends with '0', so I use the expression **phone_no LIKE '%0'**. However, the resulting recordset is empty! The same happens when using any number (not just 0) at the end of the pattern. Why? Where is the problem?

Comment: It works for me: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/saet86fNr57ywfbxUUseeo/0 - click "Run" and you'll see all the numbers ending with `0` returned, as expected.

Comment: Please show a reproducible example. (You can do it in db-fiddle.com like I did.)

Comment: Just a hunch, maybe there is whitespace at the end of your data?

Comment: @CherryDT, there are no whitespaces at the end...

Comment: OK then please export your SQL data (at least the relevant parts, enough to see the error happen) and paste it into db-fiddle together with your `SELECT` statement so that we can reproduce the issue there.